# How to write a junit test case for a method which returns a new object with arguments

Tags: java, junit

I'm new to JUnit testing. I'm trying to write test case for a getRequest() method  which returns an object with arguments.

```
class Test(  
    public Student getRequest(){
    return new Student(id, name, section);
    }
    }

    public class Student{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String section;

    public Student(String id, String name, String section){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.section=section;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Google helps for that. Have a look http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html But still need help http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve may help you and us

Comment: I'd suggest you go through the basics first. A good tutorial can be found here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I find this confusing.  You write the JUnit class to exercise methods on the class you'd like to test.  You don't just write any old method you want in the test class.

Here's the class you'd like to test:

```
public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String section;

    public Student(String id, String name, String section) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.section=section;
    }

    // Note: You'll need getters.
}
```

I'd start writing the JUnit class this way:

```
public class StudentTest { 

    @Test 
    public void testStudent_Constructor() {
        String testId = "1";
        String testName = "Foo Bar";
        String testSection = "123";

        Student student = new Student(testId, testName, testSection);    
        Assert.assertNotNull(student);
        Assert.assertEquals(testId, student.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(testName, student.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(testSection, student.getSection());
    }
}
```